# How can we read from journal on MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In a write concern mechanism, Suppose our data to be written is now available at journal and not yet passed to hard drive. Meanwhile if a read/write operation comes to the same data then how the engine will handle them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data has been written to the journal, it has also been written in memory and would be available for reads.

There is no mechanism for you to access/read the journal, but this is not necessary.

Comment: So if the query will come for the same data, it 1st search from the available data from memory instead of searching it from disk. And if the required data is not found then it goes for disk and journal is not touched. This i have got from you @helmy. Please en-light me if i am wrong.